# How to stage file hunks with gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython, git-stage

Does gitpython (or at a pinch any of the python git APIs) provide a way to stage selected hunks from a file in the working tree, like `git add -i` lets you do?

I think I can sort of see how to get an iterable of hunked changes by using `difflib` on the `git.diff.Diff`'s `a_blob` and `b_blob` properties, but then how do I stage a particular hunk?

And, for bonus points, is there a better way to iterate over changes in a file than:

```
diff = repo.head.commit.diff(None)[0]
a = diff.a_blob.read().split(b'\n')
b = diff.b_blob.read().split(b'\n')
diff_generator = difflib.Differ().compare(a, b)
```

I'm thinking something that compares the streams, rather than having to load the whole lot into memory and then splitting it into lines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a better way to construct an iterator over changes in a file.  But this is how you would stage an in-memory version of the file:

```
new_version = '........'.encode('utf-8') # Or whatever encoding you use
istream = repo.odb.store(gitdb.IStream(git.Blob.type, len(new_version), BytesIO(new_version)))
file_mode = ... # eg os.stat(file_path).st_mode
entry = git.BaseIndexEntry((file_mode, istream.binsha, 0, file_path))
repo.index.add([entry])
```

The `repo.odb.store` call stores the version in the git database, but at this point it's not linked to anything.  Creating the `BaseIndexEntry` object and adding it to the index then links that stored version into the index - the link is by the file path and the `binsha` hash.

It seems that this won't work on bare repositories.